# how to concatenate join values from modal

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i ve different scenario compare to rest posts. I ve two tables such as:

**subscription**

[image]

and 
**category**[image]

Now the columns Fruits,Snack,Sauce,lunch in **subsscription** r the id of category table. for example if `Fruits is 1` then from category table that Fruit name is `Apple`.I want to get the names of those foods whose ids are listed in **subscription table** from category table column: **itemname**.

I m working on codeigniter and tried by using joins but i dont see any values.

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('subsscription');
        $this->db->join('addschool','addschool.id=subsscription.schoolid');
        $this->db->join('user','user.id=subsscription.studentid');
        $this->db->join('category As u1','u1.id=subsscription.Fruits', 'left OUTER');

         $this->db->join('category As u2','u2.id=subsscription.snack', 'left OUTER');
         // $this->db->where('subsscription.snack >', '0');
        $this->db->join('category As u3','u3.id=subsscription.sauce', 'left OUTER');

         $this->db->join('category As u4','u4.id=subsscription.lunchdrink', 'left OUTER');

        $this->db->join('category As u5','u5.id=subsscription.icypole', 'left OUTER');

        $this->db->join('category As u6','u6.id=subsscription.lunch', 'left OUTER');
        // $this->db->where('subsscription.Fruits','category.id');
         // $this->db->group_by('subsscription.id');


        $query = $this->db->get();

        //echo $this->db->last_query();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

My output requirement is that it should be like: Apple,Strawberry Milk where Apple has row id is **1** and Strawberry Milk has row id is **4**.

Comment: You can use sub query, in the select statements. It should work. it may make the query heavier. but u have indexes then it will work.

Comment: plz explain how?? relate the example.

Comment: select subs.* , 
  ( select itemname from category where id = subs.Fruits ) as fruit_itemname
from 
 subsscription as subs

I am not able to fire this query as i dont have similar DB, but it should work.

Comment: so joins r illegal? u mean nested selections?

Comment: What is the result when you make `echo $this->db->last_query();` and run it as a query in mysql?

Comment: @user3162878, please , joins r not illegeal, but some times using other things is easier and less complex. Its your choice overall.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make it work by doing SELECT('*'). I could be wrong, it happens more often than not, but I don't think you can do that. The following worked for me. If someone else has an answer that actually does just grab everything in all of the tables, please feel free to add it.

I also left the school table out, so you'll have to work it back in. I created the tables with the pertinent information and didn't feel like making that one.

```
    $this->db->select('subsscription.id AS sub_id, user.name, u1.itemname AS fruit, u2.itemname AS snack, u3.itemname AS sauce, u4.itemname AS lunchdrink, u5.itemname AS icypole, u5.itemname AS lunch');
    $this->db->from('subsscription');
    $this->db->join('user','user.id=subsscription.studentid', 'JOIN');
    $this->db->join('category As u1','subsscription.Fruits=u1.id', 'LEFT OUTER');
    $this->db->join('category As u2','subsscription.snack=u2.id', 'LEFT OUTER');
    $this->db->join('category As u3','subsscription.sauce=u3.id', 'LEFT OUTER');
    $this->db->join('category As u4','subsscription.lunchdrink=u4.id', 'LEFT OUTER');
    $this->db->join('category As u5','subsscription.icypole=u5.id', 'LEFT OUTER');
    $this->db->join('category As u6','subsscription.lunch=u6.id', 'LEFT OUTER');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() AS $row) {
            print '<pre>' . print_r($row, TRUE) . '</pre>';
        }
    }
```

The output of this was:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [sub_id] => 1
    [name] => Betty
    [fruit] => Apple
    [snack] => 
    [sauce] => 
    [lunchdrink] => Strawberry Milk
    [icypole] => 
    [lunch] => 
)
stdClass Object
(
    [sub_id] => 2
    [name] => John
    [fruit] => Banana Bread
    [snack] => 
    [sauce] => Apple
    [lunchdrink] => 
    [icypole] => Strawberry Milk
    [lunch] => Strawberry Milk
)
```

I obviously used random values.